# For Each Dictionary loop in Index order

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, foreach, keyvaluepair

I have tried my hand using `for` loop with `Dictionary` but couldn't really achieve what I want to.

I have a certain variable `SomeVariable` and on the value of this variable I want my `foreach` to work. `SomeVariable` can be `1,2,3 or 4`

So lets say `SomeVariable` is `1` I want to retrieve the last `item.value` from among the first 3 indexes(0,1,2) inside the `SomeCollection`.

And if `SomeVariable` is `2` I want to retrieve the last `item.value` from among the next 3 indexes(3,4,5) inside the `SomeCollection`.

And so on...

```
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In SomeCollection
    If SomeVariable = 1 Then
            //....
    ElseIf SwitchCount = 2 Then
           //....
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order, so there's no reliable way to get the "first 3" inidices.

Comment: i did read that...i assume i will still want to have a go at it.

Comment: Well how do you want it to be ordered? If you have something to order your dictionary keys we could help you out

Comment: @TopinFrassi...ordering is not an issue. luckily its ordered how i want to. so i just need some help with the code or its structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary has no defined order, so any order you perceive is transient. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The order of the keys in the .KeyCollection is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the .ValueCollection returned by the Values property.

Trying to use the Keys collection to determine the order shows how it is transient:

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

For n As Int32 = 0 To 8
    myDict.Add(n, "foo")
Next

For n As Int32 = 0 To myDict.Keys.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine(myDict.Keys(n).ToString)
Next
```

the output prints 0 - 8, in order, as you might expect.  then:

```
myDict.Remove(5)
myDict.Add(9, "bar")

For n As Int32 = 0 To myDict.Keys.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine(myDict.Keys(n).ToString)
Next
```

The output is: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9 (!), 6, 7, 8

As you can see, it reuses old slots. Any code depending on things to be in a certain location will eventually break.  The more you add/remove, the more unordered it gets.  If you need an order to the `Dictionary` use `SortedDictionary` instead.

Comment: +1. Agreed.  He said he wanted to try it anyway so I just gave him an answer but you are correct in that it isn't advisable.

Comment: yea, he also said he read that, I thought I would show *why* it is a very bad idea and *how* bad.  even if it is just a lookup, since it is "unspecified" it means it could break in newer versions.

Comment: hence the +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the dictionary by index but you can access the keys collection by index.  You don't need a loop for this at all.

So something like this.

```
If SomeVariable = 1 Then
    Return SomeCollection(SomeCollection.Keys(2))
ElseIf SomeVariable = 2 Then 
    ...
End If
```

If it is truly structured you could do this:

```
Return SomeCollection(SomeCollection.Keys((SomeVariable * 3) - 1))
```

You probably need some error checking and ensuring that the length of the dictionary is correct but this should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a generic SortedDictionary, I only use C# so here's my example:

```
SortedDictionary<int,string> dict = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

foreach( KeyValuePair<int,string> kvp in dict) { ... }
```