# Is there a way to sort keys in dictionary in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Say i want to to do for each on each key and I want keys that are alphabetically smaller like "BR" to show up first.

Is there a way to do so?

Or is dictionary strictly key object pair?

Comment: the keys are not kept in any special order.  you can use a SortedDictionary if you need that. also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24438551/1070452

Comment: If the performance of this specific loop is not a concern, just call `OrderBy` on the keys, iterate over the result, and index into the dictionary.  It;s a tradeoff between the cost of sorting in this loop and keeping an entire dictionary sorted at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link as a solution

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-dictionary-vbnet

Basically insert the keys into a list and then sort that list and then enumerate based on that list.

I copy paste the sample code

```
Sub Main()
' Create Dictionary with string keys.
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
dict.Add("dog", 0)
dict.Add("cat", 1)
dict.Add("mouse", 5)
dict.Add("eel", 3)
dict.Add("programmer", 2)

' Get list of keys.
Dim keys As List(Of String) = dict.Keys.ToList

' Sort the keys.
keys.Sort()

' Loop over the sorted keys.
Dim str As String
For Each str In keys
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", str, dict.Item(str))
Next
End Sub
```