# How to get specific index of a Dictionary?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a code that returns a query result like `MySqlCommand`, all working well but what I'm trying to do is insert the result inside a `ComboBox`. The way for achieve this is the following:

1. Form load event execute the `GetAvailableCategories` function
2. The function executed download all the values and insert it into a dictionary
3. Now the dictionary returned need an iteration for each `Items` to insert in the ComboBox

**Practice example:**

1,3. Event that fire the function

```
    Private Sub Service_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For Each categoria In Categories.GetAvailableCategories()
        service_category.Items.Add(categoria)
    Next

    End Sub
```

2. `GetAvailableCategories` function

   ```
   Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

   For Each row In table.Rows

      dic.Add(row(0), row(1))

   Next

   Return dic
   ```

How you can see in the `1,3` points I call the function that return the result. What I want to do is insert the `row(0)` as value of the item and `row(1)` as Item name. But Actually I get this result in the `ComboBox`:

```
[1, Hair cut]
```

and also I can't access to a specific position of the current item in the iteration. Maybe the dictionary isn't a good choice for this operation? 

Sorry if the question could be stupid, but it's a long time since I don't program in vb.net and now I need to brush up a bit.

**UPDATE**

I've understood that I can assign the value access to the `.key` of my `dictionary`, so the result that I want achieve is correct if I do:

```
cateogoria.key (return the id of record taken from the db)
categoria.value (is the item name that'll display in the ComboBox)
```

now the problem's that: How to assign the value of the current item without create any other new class? For example:

```
service_category.Items.Add(categoria.key, categoria.value)
```

But I can't do this, any idea?

Comment: The order of items in the dictionary is not specified.  Since you access items via the key, the order is not supposed to matter.  You might want a SortedList instead

Comment: In the sorted list I can access to a specific index? I want something like associative array or a simple array that's [0] => value name

Comment: Well, a simple List<T> will give you *that*, your Dictionary would work too if you used the Key as a key rather than indexer.  `dic.Add(row(0), row(1))` is using row(0) as the key and row(1) as the value which seems odd depending on what is in it

Comment: Okay I'll take a look

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24438551/1070452

Comment: Row(0) is the record id returned from the database, and Row(1) the name of this record. So what I'm trying to do is assign to the ComboBox the item name as Row(1) and the value Row(0) But I can't access to a specific index of my dictionary.

Comment: access via the key.  `dic(cboSelectedIndex)` should give you what you want (assuming it is >-1, and there is a corresponding value).  But really, 2 bits of info like that {name and code/value} should be stored as a class object.  The CBO could show the name, but SelectedValue would be the ID you are searching for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97712/discussion-between-dillinger-and-plutonix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List` as a DataSource sounds like what you are really after.  Relying on relative indices in different arrays is sort of flaky.  There is not a lot about what these are, but a class would keep the related info together:

```
Public Class Service
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Category As String
    Public Property Id As Int32
End Class
```

This will keep the different bits of information together.  Use them to store the info read from the db and use a List to store all of them:\

```
Private Services As New List(of Service)
...

For Each row In table.Rows

   Dim s As New Service
   s.Name = row(0).ToString()    '???
   s.Category =...
   s.Id = ...
   Services.Add(s)          ' add this item to list
Next
```

Finally, bind the List to the CBO:

```
myCbo.DataSource = Services
myCbo.DisplayMember = "Name"            ' what to show in cbo
myCbo.ValueMember = "Id"                ' what to use for SelectedValue
```

I dont really know what you want to show or what the db fields read are, so I am guessing.  But the larger point is that a Class will keep the different bits of info together better than an array.  The List can be the DataSource so that you dont even have to populate the CBO directly.  The List can also be Sorted, searched, Filtered and so forth with linq.

When the user picks something, `myCbo.SelectedItem` should **be** that item (though it will need to be cast), or you can use `SelectedIndex` to find it in the list:

```
thisOne = Services(myCbo.SelectedIndex)
```

It is also usually a good idea to override `ToString` in the item/service class.  This will determine what shows when a `DisplayMember` mapping is not available.  Without this, `WindowsApp2.Service` might show for your items:

```
Public Overrides ToString() As String
    Return String.Format("{0}  ({1})", Name, Price)
End Sub
```

This would show something like

> Haircut  ($12.30)

Comment: But a this point I can use the .key as you said. There's a way to add the value as a key? Check my update

Comment: The items collection isnt going to let you add 2 elements for one item (`service_category.Items.Add(categoria.key, categoria.value)`).  Thats the point behind using a DataSource - all the bits of info stay together in the class object and are easily available and your List always has the same contents as the CBO.  The CBO will give you selected item as SelectedItem without having to find it in some other collection or array

Comment: Okay now it's clear, thank your for explain it what I need, have a nice day :)

Comment: Why now I can't fire SelectIndexChange?

Comment: Of course I have no idea how you implemented it.  A control using a datasource will still fire `SelectedIndexChanged` events, typically you'd be more interested in the `SelectedItemChanged` though. `I can't fire...` are **you** trying to force events?

Comment: What do you mean when say: force the event? In the Handles I've only .SelectValueChanged, .SelectIndexChanged, .SelectChangeCommited; nope not working

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant `.SelectValueChanged`; they both should be firing when the user selects a different item.  Since this is all new to you it is entirely possible you missed a step or something (Are the names showing in the CBO?).  You should post a new question showing how you populate things and what isnt working

Comment: Okay now with your hint I fixed but how I can get the text selected? I use: selectCustomer.SelectedText but I get an empty result and also with SelectedItem

Comment: `SelectedText` is probably not what you think it is, and not what you want with a datasource.  I HAVE NO IDEA how you crafted this, but if the name is what shows, then cast `SelectedItem` to a Service item (Again, no idea of the names you used) then use the `Name` property.  eg:  `thisOne = Ctype(cbo.SelectedItem, Service) : theName = thisOne.Name`  The cbo now contains *objects* so you can use the properties you created for that class

Comment: I just want get the valueMember name. Your solution working thank you :)