# deleting the last key in a dictionary

Tags: vb.net

One of the keys in my dictionary is like this == > O "Models"

I want to delete this key. I know that this will be the last key always

I tried:

```
file1dictionary.Remove(O "Models")
file1dictionary.Remove("O "Models"")
```

Both have syntax errors

Comment: The order of items in a dictionary is undefined so you cant go by the order (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24438551).  If there really are embedded quotes then escape them: `"O """"Models"""""`

Comment: @Plutonix : Isn't that too many quotes? Shouldn't it be: `"O ""Models"""`?

Comment: @VisualVincent  Yes, you are correct.  Way, too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes in VB.Net strings are self-escaped, meaning you use two of them within the string literal to represent a quote contained in the string object, like this:

```
file1dictionary.Remove("O ""Models""")
```